# How to create a github repository from the cli with git using only a token?

Tags: git, github, token, push, git-push

With github tokens, the easiest way I've found to work with a new repository is.

```
1. Create the new repo on the github site.
2. git clone https://[user]:ghp_asdcsdcasdcasdcasdcasdcasdc@github.com/[user]/repo-name.git   # Using token to authenticate
3. cd into that new folder and then put files in here and then add / commit / push
git add .  ;  git commit -m "test"  ;  git status  ;   git push -u origin master
```

This works, but cannot do the process purely from the cli, requiring the step on the site.

However, the "official" way (presented on the github site) is:

```
echo "# test-xxx" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/[user]/repo-name.git 
git push -u origin master
```

Obviously, password authentication is no longer available, so this automatically fails. So I updated the remote add origin to be `git remove add origin https://[user]:ghp_asdcsdcasdcasdcasdcasdcasdc@github.com/[user]/repo-name.git`

But this completely fails with the error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/[user]/repo-name.git/' not found
```

So the official way is broken (because it assumes that password authentication is going to work, but password authentication was removed in August 2021).

From cli, how do I create a repository under my account (using a token, not a password) and then start pushing changes to that repository?

Comment: *password authentication is no longer available*...  Right; *so this automatically fails* ... but this doesn't follow: when you get prompted for a user name and a password, you simply enter the user name and then the *token*. If you're not getting a prompt, the lack of a prompt is the problem, not the switch from passwords to tokens.

Comment: I see. When I am prompted for password, I think "it wants a password" and not "it wants a token". I've just tested that and it also completely fails. Putting the token in as the password fails for me. `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/[user]/repo-name.git/' not found`. I still have no way to create a repo from the cli such that it can authenticate with github when I push it. Do you know how to do that? The `remote add origin` step does not seem to do anything.

Comment: The token definitely should work here. The hardcoded user:password-or-token@github.com stuff should work too, but it's generally a bad idea since then your user name and token (used to be password) are there in cleartext for everyone to see. Personally, I always try to use ssh myself, to avoid all of this http craziness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works, but cannot do the process purely from the cli, requiring the step on the site.

You don't have to do any step on the site, if you have installed locally the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/)

You can then:

- [login to GitHub](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) (from local command line):

  ```
  gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt
  ```
- [create a new repository on GitHub](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) (from local command line):

  ```
  git init my-project
  cd my-project
  gh repo create
  ```

---

In the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238655/discussion-between-vonc-and-yorsubs), the OP settled on:

> Create the repo using `gh`:
>
> ```sh
> gh auth login --with-token < ~/.token
> git init my-project
> cd my-project
> gh repo create my-project --confirm --public
> cd ..; rm -rfi my-project; 
> git clone --depth=1 https://[user]:[token]@github.com/[user]/[my-project]
> ```

Comment: I've downloaded `gh` and it seemed partly to work. `✓ Created repository [user]/my-project on GitHub`, `✓ Added remote https://github.com/[user]/my-project.git`. However, when I then try `git push -u origin master`, I get errors `error: src refspec master does not match any`, `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[user]/my-project.git'`. I also tried `origin main` (due to the demented "Social Justice" demands to change `master` to `main`, and that also fails). Any idea why I cannot push to this repo?

Comment: @YorSubs do a `git status` and `git branch -avv` With recent versions of Git, the default branch is called `main`, no longer `master`. Try `git push -u origin main`

Comment: @YorSubs If your local branch is indeed master, then it would be `git push -u origin master:main`

Comment: @YorSubs But in any case, make sure you have made at least one commit locally (`git status` and `git log` should confirm this)

Comment: I wiped everything and started again, and this time it worked, thanks (oh, and `gh` is great, thanks for that, had not seen it before). However, on every subsequent `git push` it is repeatedly asking for my username and password (for which I use the token as @torek advised, and he was right, got this working eventually). So the last step I need is to be able to save the token so that it is authorised for all `git push` actions. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @YorSubs Yes, for HTTPS URL, make sure to set `git config--global credential.manager manager-core`, assuming Windows. If not Windows, install GCM-core (https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) for Mac or Linux. With the next push, enter your GitHub user account name, and token: they will be cached, and Git won't ask for them ever again.

Comment: Thanks. Installed that, ran `git config--global credential.manager manager-core` but that failed, tried again with `git config --global credential.credentialStore secretservice` (from https://techoverflow.net/2021/09/19/how-to-fix-git-credential-manager-core-git-fatal-no-credential-backing-store-has-been-selected/) but that also failed (at the push step, my cli, ubuntu, just gets stuck, and I have to Ctrl-C out of it).

Comment: @YorSubs You need to make sure the `git-credential-manager-core` executable is in your $PATH, and you must have set `credential.credentialStore` indeed: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#freedesktoporg-secret-service-api. Ideally to `secretservice`, assuming you have a GUI/X graphical layer. But if you don't (headless environnement, command-line only), then https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#headlesstty-only-sessions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238655/discussion-between-vonc-and-yorsubs).